# Convert image from 4500x5400 to 4050x4200 keeping aspect ratio

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image of 4500x5400, I want to resize it for the height 4200 keeping the width ratio, however the width of the image needs to be 4050, leaving the sides transparent.

I have this ImageMagick command:

```
convert file.png -resize 4500x5400 -gravity center -background transparent -extent 4050x4200 out.png
```

However it's cutting the top and the bottom, while it needs to appear.

Do you guys have any idea of how I can make it work?

Appreciate your time!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You say you have an image of 4500x5400 yet the first thing you do in your command is resize it to the size you say it already is... ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out, I need to resize this 4500x5400 file into a height of 4200 keeping the width ratio. This image should be placed into a 4050x4200 transparent box with both sides without content.

like this:

Comment: If you want the height to be 4200, use `-resize x4200`

Comment: Yes, however this command cuts the part of the image.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

https://i.imgur.com/110Y8ci.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
convert input.png -resize 4050x4200 -background none -gravity center -extent 4050x4200 output.png
```

The "-resize" fits your input image within a container of that size. The "-extent" makes sure the total canvas is that size. The "-background" and "-gravity" make sure extra space is filled with transparent and that the input image is located in the center of the output canvas.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much. 

However I want to know why using the command -resize 4050x4200 doesn't shrink the image? It is keeping the aspect ratio. That's what I want, just to understand the command out.

Best,

Comment: The "-resize" operator in its simplest form will change the size of the image to fit within the dimensions given, but not necessarily fill those dimensions. It keeps the aspect ratio. There are several ways to use "-resize", and you can force it to match your given dimensions in both directions, but that's not the default behavior. Find some details at this link...

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize

Comment: Thank you GeeMack! Appreciate your time!